# JUnit ArrayList Empty

Tags: java, arraylist, junit

I'm new in JUnit testing and i found nothing like my problem on the Internet. The problem is simple:

I have a JForm with basic textfields like "name" or "adress". To fill them, i import a CSV-File with the content. Everything works fine, i've got a main class with the method "readCSV" who puts everything in the form. In my GUI class i do an instance of the main class and execute the method. In the GUI class i also got a "searchPerson" method which also works fine.

The InOut method takes a static ArrayList and compares if there is already a person with the same name.

```
public class InOut {
static ArrayList<Personen> personen;

public InOut(ArrayList<Personen> personen) {
this.personen = personen;
}


static public ArrayList<Personen> searchPerson(String Vorname, String Nachname){
    ArrayList<Personen> gefundenePersonen = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Personen p: personen){
        if(p.name.contains(Nachname)||Nachname == "" || Vorname == "Kein Treffer"){
            if(p.vorname.contains(Vorname) || Vorname == "")
            gefundenePersonen.add(p);
        }
    }
    return gefundenePersonen;
}
```

Now i need to make a JUnit Test in which i need to search for a person. The problem is that the import of the CSV-File in the test won't work.

```
public class AdressverwaltungGUIIT {
    static AdressverwaltungGUI adg;
    static int counter;
    main csvImport = new main();
    ArrayList<Personen> personen;

public AdressverwaltungGUIIT() {
    try {
        this.personen = csvImport.readCSV();
       System.out.print(personen);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AdressverwaltungGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}


@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.adg = new AdressverwaltungGUI();
    adg.setVisible(true);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
}

/**
 * Test of main method, of class AdressverwaltungGUI.
 */
@Test
public void search() throws InterruptedException {
    JButton search = (JButton)getChildNamed(adg, "searchButton");
    assertNotNull(adg);
    JTextField name = (JTextField)getChildNamed(adg, "nameField");
    assertNotNull(name);
    JTextField firstName = (JTextField)getChildNamed(adg, "firstNameField");
    assertNotNull(firstName);
    JTextField street = (JTextField)getChildNamed(adg, "streetField");
    assertNotNull(street);




    System.out.print("-");
    System.out.print(personen);
    System.out.print("-");

    name.setText("Mueller");
    sleep(2000);
    firstName.setText("Peter");
    sleep(2000);

    InOut inOut = new InOut(personen);
    ArrayList<Personen> personen = inOut.searchPerson(firstName.getText(), name.getText());
    if(personen.size() > 0){
        firstName.setText(personen.get(0).vorname);
        name.setText(personen.get(0).name);

    }else{
        firstName.setText("Kein Treffer");
    }  

    search.doClick();
    assertEquals("Sonnenweg", street.getText());
}
```

When i print out the ArrayList of my persons the list is empty but in the normal GUI, when i do the exact same the list is full with persons and their attributs. Can someone help me?

Comment: Vorname == "Kein Treffer" is not correct way to check equality use "Kein Treffer".equals(Vorname ) instead

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Comment: StringUtils.equals(Vorname, "Kein Treffer"); is even better

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` instead of `==` for comparison in `search` method.

```
    static public ArrayList<Personen> searchPerson(String Vorname, String Nachname){
        ArrayList<Personen> gefundenePersonen = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Personen p: personen){
            if(p.name.contains(Nachname)||Nachname.equals("")|| Vorname.equals("Kein Treffer")){
                if(p.vorname.contains(Vorname) || Vorname.equals(""))
                gefundenePersonen.add(p);
            }
        }
        return gefundenePersonen;
    }
```

Comment: the problem at hand is that the loading of the cvs file in test env does not work

Comment: @aurelius is there no way to do this in a test env?

Comment: maybe the cvs file is not present in the test env. Or you can mock the readCVS output.

Comment: @aurelius well as you can see in the constructor there's a line with: this.personen = csvImport.readCSV(); . That should put the output of the readCSV method in an ArrayList but this list is empty. In the main class it works with the exact same code.

Comment: that's why I mentioned the environment configs, you might have different paths for the same file, the path in dev env might be different than the one in test env